# Mocking validator in Laravel with Mockery returning call to member function on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, mockery

I'm trying to implement some unit tests for my REST controller. Everything works fine until I use the Validator facade. The index and show tests are working fine.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function setAttributeName() on a non-object in D:\....\controllers\AllergyController.
```

My code is:

```
//Unit test
class AllergyControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->allergy = $this->mock('App\Modules\Patient\Repositories\IAllergyRepository');
    }

    public function mock($class)
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock($class);

        $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

        return $mock;
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->allergy->shouldReceive('all')->once();

        $this->call('GET', 'api/allergy');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }

    public function testShow()
    {
        $this->allergy->shouldReceive('find')->once()->andReturn(array());

        $this->call('GET', 'api/allergy/1');

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }

    public function testStore()
    {
        $validator = Mockery::mock('stdClass');
        Validator::swap($validator);

        $input = array('name' => 'foo');

        $this->allergy->shouldReceive('create')->once();
        $validator->shouldReceive('make')->once();
        $validator->shouldReceive('setAttributeNames')->once();

        $this->call('POST', 'api/allergy', $input);

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
class AllergyController extends \App\Controllers\BaseController
{
    public function __construct(IAllergyRepository $allergy){
        $this->allergy = $allergy;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function store()
    {
        //define validation rules
        $rules = array(
            'name' => Config::get('Patient::validation.allergy.add.name')
        );

        //execute validation rules
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        $validator->setAttributeNames(Config::get('Patient::validation.allergy.messages'));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response::json(array('status' => false, 'data' => $validator->messages()));
        } else {
            $allergy = $this->allergy->create(Input::all());

            if ($allergy) {
                return Response::json(array('status' => true, 'data' => $allergy));
            } else {
                $messages = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
                $messages->add('error', 'Create failed! Please contact the site administrator or try again!');

                return Response::json(array('status' => false, 'data' => $messages));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to fgure out why it's throwing this error. When I call the controller with a normal api call it works fine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably wanting to return the validator double from the stubbed `make` call.

```
$validator->shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn($validator);
```